# How do I truncate strings?

Tags: 7

For example, I need to truncate the following text.

> Drupal is free, flexible, robust and constantly being improved by hundreds of thousands of passionate people from all over the world. Join us!

I have used `drupal_substr()`, but the result may be "Drupal is free, flexi."
How can I avoid to truncate a word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use **[truncate_utf8()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--unicode.inc/function/truncate_utf8/7)** using `$wordsafe = TRUE;`

> **$wordsafe** Flag to truncate at last space within the upper limit. Defaults to FALSE.